# Android Studio Library Projects (Modules) show up as different Build Variants

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio so please forgive me if this question has been answered or the reason is obvious, but.....

All of my library project dependency modules are showing up with different build variants in the Build Variants pane of Android Studio.

For example, my app uses the library project DragSortListView and I've imported that as a Module in Android Studio.  Everything runs and compiles just fine, but I don't understand why this library module (along with the other library modules) is listed in the Build Variants pane.  Is this normal or am I setting up my project incorrectly?  See the screenshot below ::

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. It isn't showing each module as a different build variant, it's showing you each module in your project and allowing you to choose which build variant you want to build for that individual module. The actual build variants are selectable in the right-hand column of that view.